# "Error: Missing actual argument 'repeatable' in call to 'random_init' " showing up when using gcc/9.3.0 to compile fortran code

Tags: fortran

I have a large code written in Fortran, divided into multiple files. In one of the files, "parRandom_Init.f90", there is a subroutine called 'random_init' which is used to initialize an array with random numbers. Here is the piece of code for that:

```
subroutine random_init
USE CurrentProblemValues, ONLY : seed

IMPLICIT NONE

integer :: values(1:8), k, j
!integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: seed

call date_and_time(values=values)
call random_seed(size=k)
allocate(seed(1:k))
j = values(8)**5 - 1
if (j.le.0) j = (2**30 - 1) + j !** if integer overflow occurs
seed(:) = j
call random_seed(put=seed)
write(*,*) 'Initializing pseudorandom numbers:'
write(*,*)   ((seed(j)), j = 1,k)
write(*,*) ((values(j)), j = 1,8)

return
end subroutine random_init
```

This subroutine is being called by another file. I used to be able to compile this set of files using `mpif90 -o test.out par*.f90` without any issues using gcc/8.3.0 (the other files also begin with par...). When my system was updated to gcc/9.3.0 and I try to compile, I get an error:

> 512 |         call random_init

> Error: Missing actual argument 'repeatable' in call to 'random_init' at (1)

I am confused by this error because this subroutine does not take any arguments, and this error did not show up with the previous version of gcc compiler.

Here is a code snippet from the subroutine that is calling it:

```
! initialize the seed values for random numbers generators
 IF (Rank_of_process.EQ.0) THEN
    call random_init
    call random_seed(put=seed)
    call sgrnd(seed(1))

    PRINT '(/2x,"Process ",i3," : Seed for the random number generator: ",i12)', Rank_of_process, seed(1)
    DO i = 1, N_of_processes - 1
       itmp = int(2.d0**31 * grnd())
       if (itmp.le.0) itmp = (2**31 - 1) + itmp
       CALL MPI_SEND(itmp, 1, MPI_INTEGER, i, 101, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    END DO
 ELSE
    CALL MPI_RECV(I_random_seed, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, 101, MPI_COMM_WORLD, stattus, ierr)
    call random_init
    seed(:) = I_random_seed
    call random_seed(put=seed)
    call sgrnd(seed(1))
    PRINT '(2x,"Process ",i3," : received the random numbers generator seed: ",i12)', Rank_of_process, I_random_seed
 END IF
 CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
```

Has anybody seen this error before? What does 'repeatable' mean? Are there any specific compiler flags I should use to get rid of this error?

Thank you for reading. Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide.

Comment: We need to see more. Is there an interface in scope for this routine at the point it is *called*. Is this routine in a module? Is that module used in the routine that tries to call it? The most likely explanation is at the calling point the only interface available is to the intrinsic function `random_init` - rather than yours. You would get such an error if this is the case. Yet another reason for always putting routines in modules and using them at the calling point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have made some edits to show where this subroutine is being called. It is not part of a module. Only the variable 'seed' is from the module 'CurrentProblemValues'.
I looked up the intrinsic function 'random_init' which indeed has an argument called 'repeatable'. Did gcc/9.3 make it stricter to put routines in modules, because this wasn't an issue in gcc/8.3.0?

Comment: `random_init` is an intrinsic routine introduced in (I think) fortran 2018. What's likely happened is the new compiler implements the new intrinsic, while the older doesn't. If you show us a complete code showing the problem it will be much easier to discuss - just the cut the relevant bits out of your code, it should only take a few lines - But what you have added is of no use, we need to see what is in scope, and code snippets don't show that.

Comment: Your code is really incomplete. If your own `random_init` is external, use the `external` attribute to declare it in the calling scope. Or an interface block. Or best, put it in a module and use this module. We have duplicates about this kind of error.

Comment: `RANDOM_INIT` is a Fortran intrinsic subprogram.  It was added to gfortran in the `9.1` release.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63570

Comment: Just put your `random_init` in a module and, even better, rename it. Preferably both.